# removing the need for boost::bind in my function

Tags: c++, function, templates, events, boost

This is a mid level question. I register my events in c++ by storing a pointer to a function. 
Currently, i store the function in a `boost::function<void (Event*)>`, and that function shall take a pointer to the event as a parameter when the event is fired.

To register a new event, I do this..

```
Event::Register("click", "Image18", boost::bind(&MyMenu::OnClick, this, _1));

MyMenu::OnClick(DKEvent* event)  <-- calls this
```

I would like to simplify the user end of my code as much as possible.
How can I push the boost::bind method into the Event class. I would like to slim down registering events, to something like this. less is good.

```
Event::Register("click", "Image18", &MyMenu::OnClick, this);
```

This may involve using c++ Templates as the class's referenced are not always the same. Can someone give me a quick look how I can achieve this.

Comment: Can you show the current interface and relevant bits of the implementation of `Even::Register`?

Comment: variadic templates has solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `Event::Register` into a template function taking a member function and instance as parameters:

```
//templated on the class and the return type and args of the member function
template <class T, typename Ret, typename... Args>
void Event::Register (std::string, std::string, Ret (T::*) (Args...), T*);
```

You don't even need to supply the template arguments here, the compiler will deduce them for you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need *variadic templates*

```
template<typename... Args>
void Event::Register(std::string ID, Args... args)
{
   auto bind = std::bind(args...);
}
```

No need for `boost::bind`.

Answer (score 1):

You are limiting your user and forcing him to user a member pointer function on an instance if you do that, whereas if you let it as it is you'll benefit from the multiple sources that can bind to an `std::function` including lambdas and free functions, IMO your current form is way better than the one you want to achieve.

It is probably better to let the user of your class choose if he wants to bind an instance to a member function or not, and you will complicate your interface by providing multiple template overloads like `boost::bind` does.

Comment: I left the original functionality in place as well, it may serve a good purpose in the future as you suggest :)

Comment: @aquawicket Good choice :)